# Fit ImageView to LinearLayout inside HorizontalScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, image-scaling

Hei, I have a hor scrollview which holds a LinearLayout (orientation: hor).

```
     <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/adImageScroller"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/adImageViewContainer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:background="@color/material_blue_grey_950">
        </LinearLayout>

    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

I am populating this LinearLayout dynamically with ImageViews (all images have random aspect ratios).

This is the onCreateView method which populates the LinearLayout:

```
for (int i = 0; i < reObjectPicUrls.size(); i++) {
        String url = reObjectPicUrls.get(i).getContent();
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getActivity());

        imageView.setId(i);
        imageView.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);
        new DownloadImageTask(imageView)
                .execute(url);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_START); //<-- WORKS IN XML
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)); //<-- WORKS IN XML
        imageViewContainer.addView(imageView);
}
```

What I need but don't get is all images to be scaled to the height of the grey area (horizontalScrollView height) while sustaining their aspect ratio.

The images are all scaled down with `options.inSampleSize = 4;`

Problem is in the image below. The images are not scaled to fit the height of the LinearLayout.
[image]

I have tried different scaleType but nothing seems to fix it.
Thanks for any tips on how to fix this.

Comment: try to give min height to imageview

Comment: Good idea, but I need to support multiple screen sizes so I am using layout_weight instead of height. Giving min height would post question of what the min heigth should be.

Comment: min height can be depending on your screen size ...take device height width and divide by 2 or 3 that will support in all screen size

Comment: You will not be able to make that using only xml , you should set the imageview size based on its image size and use scaletype fitXY

Comment: As I understand ImageView size should just be matching with the LinearLayout if I want the image to fill the height of the LinearLayout (grey area). In that case I cannot set ImageView height depending on the image size. Images can be small but they then need to be streched out.

Answer (score 1):

Finally cracked it.
Didn't have to change the layout xml but did alter the onCreateView code and added `setAdjustViewBounds(true)` also used FIT_CENTER scale type.

```
for (int i = 0; i < reObjectPicUrls.size(); i++) {
        String url = reObjectPicUrls.get(i).getContent();
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getActivity());

        imageView.setId(i);
        imageView.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);
        new DownloadImageTask(imageView)
                .execute(url);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true); <--- THIS DID THE TRICK
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);

        imageViewContainer.addView(imageView);
}
```